# Mostrar imagenes alojadas en otro disco del servidor con HTML

Tags: html5, xampp, img, src

Les comento mi problema, tengo un sistema web con HTML, JQuery y PHP montado en XAMPP el cual sube una imagen y la guarda en un disco diferente del servidor web (En C: esta mi servidor y las imágenes las guardo en F:), "aclaro que los 2 discos se encuentran en el mismo server", después de eso, intento mostrar esas imágenes en un  mi duda es, ¿Cómo debo especificar la ruta en el src="" para que encuentre esas imágenes?

Les agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Lo puedes conseguir desde Apache con un [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que en vez de hacer eso, con PHP obtengas la imagen y la conviertas en un blob, luego este blob lo muestres en el Frontend, debido a que hacerlo de otra forma se vería muy extraña la dirección y pudiese hasta no cargar dicha imagen.

> ¿Cómo puedes hacerlo?

```
<?php
$file= 'F:/ejemplo/myimage.png'; //Ruta de la imágen (Esto es solo un ejemplo)
$type = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$image = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
```

Espero te sirva la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente hermano, me funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias.

Comment: Es un gusto ayudar, no olvides marcarla como la correcta.